# How to compile a program and open the output in a vertical terminal window?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, terminal-buffer, makeprg

How can I write a command that does the following?

- With one mapping, compile and/or run a program based on the filetype (`*.c`,
  `*.cpp`, `*.js`, `*.py`, etc.), and open a vertical terminal window with
  the output.
- With *another* mapping, close the vertical terminal window.

I know you can open the terminal next to Vim with `tmux`, but I want to do it with just Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is basically a 2 part question.

1. Can you compile a program in vim, yes
   `:make` will run your Makefile, you can also set `makeprg` to your compile program if its different.

type `:he :make` and `:he makeprg` for more info

2. Can you see the output of a command in vim, yes

`:vertical terminal ++shell ++cols=40 dir` Will run the command `dir` and show the output in a vertical split window.

So combining these together, you get this

`nnoremap <c-m> :make<cr>:vertical terminal ++shell ++cols=40 YourProgram.exe<cr>`

type `:he :vertical` and `:he :terminal` for more info

An additional tip, to close the window `<C-w>c` is a default keybind in Vim to do that for you.

Comment: but how to manage extension .c , .cpp , .py ?

Comment: @Visrut for that, set your makeprg appropriately (based on filetype or project structure or some other mechanism). And you can adjust the map to be more generic (“run the program in the variable `b:compiled_program`, for example, and set that variable too)

Comment: @D.ben Knoble  if you know vim script than please write your answer, if you found any way to do that because I don't know vim script very well.

Comment: @Visrut For applying different settings to different file types, have a read of `:help ftplugin-overrule`

Comment: May I add that in most cases we don't need to change `makeprg` for languages supported by gnumake implicit rules, i.e. C++, C, and Fortran at least -- there may be other languages. However, the right compilation command would be `:make %<` for single file programs. And to execute the result it would be `:vert term ./%<`. Also, for some languages, proper `'makeprg`, and `errorformat` are provided through compiler plugins (`:h compiler`)

Comment: I get some issues with neovim , I think terminal not properly shown , we have to use plugin called floatterm in nvim , so anybody know how to do that